# Finding Steady state using markov chains. Am I right?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

Suppose that there are two doctors in a country town, Dr Black and Dr White. Each year, 13% of patients move from Dr Black to Dr White, while 19% of patients move from Dr White to Dr Black. Suppose that initially 33% of patients go to Dr Black and 67% go to Dr White. Find the percentage of patients who will eventually be attending each doctor if this pattern continues indefinitely.

Ok, so I said the transition matrix $T=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.87 & 0.19 \\
   0.13 & 0.81 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
 And that led me to say that eventually 59.4% of patients will go to Dr Black and 40.6% will go to Dr. White. But my textbook disagrees. Is my transition Matrix wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your calculations seems correct to me, with the exception it is 0.594 to White and 0.406 to Black. This assumes your first row/column is white and the second is black.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your book answer?

Comment: 51.8% to Black and 48.2 to White

Comment: Your work looks good to me!